# Close price of crypto

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency

How do we define close price for crypto? I am looking at Yahoo price, as we know, the BTC is 24 hours. How does the close price defined in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo uses Coinmarketcap.
[image]

[Coinmarketcap defines](https://support.coinmarketcap.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016193231-Market-Open-and-Close-Times#:%7E:text=The%20market%20opens%20at%2012,and%20when%20the%20market%20closes.) it as such:

> The market opens at 12:00 AM (00:00) and closes at 11:59 PM (23:59)
> UTC time.
>
> For the Historical Tab of a Coin/Token, we take a snapshot when the
> market opens and when the market closes.
>
> Data is collected, recorded, and reported in UTC time unless otherwise
> specified.

a quick comparison shows that this is indeed the case.
[image]